# How can I recreate this shadow with a gap or offset?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shadows

I have been trying for hours to make this kind of shadow in Photoshop (the red one). Can somebody help me? Notice that there is a gap between the font and the shadow.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just two type layers.

The top type layer has a white fill and a blue stroke.

The bottom type layer has a simple red fill.

[image]

You could also simply use a hard-edged drop shadow on a single type layer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. thanks for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 3):

[Scott's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/28141/12189) is very good. I would take it just a step further by creating **3 type layers** in order to account for the overlap of the white lettering over the green.  Check out the triangle of the "A" or the hole of the "P".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like both answers, but I'd take it a step back :)

I think all this can be done in a single layer with 2 layer styles. Stroke and Drop Shadow. You can play around with the style settings to get the right look.

The advantage of having it in one layer is that it makes editing of your text very easy. If you use multiple layers you would have to edit the text multiple times whenever you need to change the copy.

Comment: Isn't this what I posted (second part)?

Comment: sorry, just saw the initial part :)